# Source maps for angular elements compiled build when hosted in separate application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-elements

We have a project where we create a based on Angular elements that subsequently get renders widgets in a separate host web app. Basically this host app dynamically renders up the web components contained in the angular elements application and displays them in a layout.

The compiled minified output of the angular elements app is hosted on a separate server to the host app (we are using a microservice architecture).

The issue I am trying to resolve is how can I maintain functioning source maps for the compiled angular elements project such that we can debug with tiebacks to the original type script source files. 
At the moment we are only able to 'pretty print' the minified file and debug that way. Getting the source maps included is not a problem... the issue is that the source tree is not visible and thus we cant set breakpoints.

I would like to be able to view the source files tree in the developer tools and set break points on the typescript code.

Any suggestions on how I can approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I was able to use this to get it working :
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Once I had the package installed and I did a build with it confirured to use 'eval' I was able to see my typescript source files in the developer tools.

Comment: can you specify please where to put the this 'eval' value